# storing dynamic text input into database

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, servlets, dynamic-forms

Insert Dynamic text input values into mysql using servlets

I have a form where i use a javascript to add additional text fields.
how can i store these values in the database?
in my servlet, when i try to the request.getParameterValues() , i get 
 java.lang.NullPointerException

this is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="ServletDB" name="submissionForm" id="submissionForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
 <div id="authors">
   <b>Author 1</b><br/>
   <b>Name:    </b><input type='text' name='name[]'><br/>
   <b>Surname:</b><input type='text' name='surName[]'><br/>
   <b>Email:</b><input type='text' name='eMail[]'><br/>
   <b>Affiliations:</b><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='affiliations[]'></textarea>   <br/>

 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Add Author" onClick="addAuth('authors');">
```

this is my javascript

```
var authCount = 1;
```

function addAuth(authDiv){

```
      var newAuth = document.createElement('div');
      newAuth.innerHTML = "Author " + (authCount + 1) + "<br/> <b>Name:    </b><input type='text' name='name[]'><br/><b>Surname:</b><input type='text' name='surName[]'><br/><b>Email:</b><input type='text' name='eMail[]'><br/><b>Affiliations:</b><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='affiliations[]'></textarea><br/>";
      document.getElementById(authDiv).appendChild(newAuth);
      authCount++;
 }
```

implementation in DoPost of servlet:

```
String[] name = req.getParameterValues("name");
          String[] surName = req.getParameterValues("surName");
          String[] eMail = req.getParameterValues("eMail");
          String[] affiliations = req.getParameterValues("affiliations");

          int authCount = name.length;

          boolean rs1 = true;
          try {
          // Load the database driver
          Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
          // Get a Connection to the database
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection
          (connectionURL, "root",""); 
          //Add the data into the database
          for(int i=0;i<authCount;i++){
          String sql ="INSERT INTO mytable.author(articleld,Surname,FirstName,Email,) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
          PreparedStatement pst = 
          connection.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1,surName[i]);
          pst.setString(3,name[i]);
          pst.setString(4,eMail[i]);

          out.println(pst);
          rs1=pst.execute();
          pst.close();
          }
```